# Как оптимизировать запрос к API

Tags: javascript, php, api

Есть API где я могу получить за один запрос данные только за текущий день. Проблема в том что если мне надо будет достать данные за 30 дней, то мне надо будет слать 30 запросов с разными датами. Кто нибудь знает как можно оптимизировать данный подход? Возможность поставить диапазон дат в API нет(все надо делать на клиенте).

Comment: Написать разработчикам АПИ чтобы добавили возможность получать данные за период.

Answer (score 4):

Самый правильный вариант — обратиться к разработчикам API и добавить недостающие методы. Поймите, им ведь тоже не нужен этот DOS, когда их бомбардируют запросами.

На вашей стороне возможности сильно ограничены, у вас немного вариантов и все так себе:

- кеширование запросов в локальную базу (вдруг повезёт и потребуются сначала данные с января по март, а потом с февраля по апрель) — значительный минус тут, что сохранённые данные будут со временем отличаться от полученных через сервис
- распараллеливание запросов
- префетчинг запросов (делать запросы заранее, чем ещё вам потребовались данные)

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизировать можно пожалуй только сделав мультипоточный запрос, в PHP есть варианты реализации на сокетах и [[multi]Curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php)